# Error conversion String BigDecimal

Tags: java, apache, type-conversion, struts

I am in a project where in I am using struts for the first time when I click on the submit button of my JSP page I am getting the following error can anyone find me out of this

Exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate
org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:495)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:805)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Root cause

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: BeanUtils.populate
org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:495)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:805)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Root cause

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:534)
java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:728)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BigDecimalConverter.convert(BigDecimalConverter.java:112)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.convert(ConvertUtilsBean.java:428)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1004)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:811)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:298)
org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:493)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:805)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:203)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

This is my action page:

```
 package it.gepo.cflow.tracking.viewcontroler;

import it.gepo.cflow.tracking.dao.CtrkCheckListBean;
import it.gepo.cflow.tracking.dao.CtrkCheckListDAO;
import it.gepo.cflow.tracking.dao.CtrkCliClassiDAO;
import it.gepo.cflow.tracking.dao.CtrkModuliIndiciBean;
import it.gepo.cflow.tracking.dao.CtrkModuliIndiciDAO;
import it.gepo.cflow.utility.UtilityCtrk;
import it.gepo.utility.GepoUtility;
import it.gepo.web.ConnectionFactory;
import it.gepo.web.GepoUtente;
import it.gepo.web.MyAction;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessage;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class TrackingChecklistAction extends MyAction {

    public static Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(TrackingChecklistAction.class);
    public static int righeTabella = 10;
    public static int righeTabellaNew = 1;
    public static boolean unRecordXPagina = false;
    public static String nomeForm = "TrackingChecklistForm";

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("execute");
        Connection conn = null;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        GepoUtente gepoUtente = (GepoUtente) session.getAttribute("GepoUtente");
        String dataSourceName = gepoUtente.getDataSource();

        try {

            conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection(dataSourceName);
            TrackingChecklistForm myForm = (TrackingChecklistForm) form;
            if (mapping.getParameter().equals("visualizza")) {
                return visualizza(mapping, myForm, request, response, session,
                        conn);
            } else if (mapping.getParameter().equals("gestione")) {
                return gestione(mapping, myForm, request, response, session,
                        conn);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("errore " + e.getMessage());
            ActionMessages errors = new ActionMessages();
            ActionMessage error = new ActionMessage("errore.generico",
                    e.getMessage(), e);
            errors.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, error);
            saveErrors(request, errors);
            return mapping.getInputForward();
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ServletException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private ActionForward visualizza(ActionMapping mapping,
            TrackingChecklistForm myForm, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session, Connection conn)
            throws IOException, ServletException, Exception {

        logger.debug("visualizza");

        List lista = null;
        CtrkCheckListDAO dao = null;

        //
        // Primo Ingresso
        //
        if (myForm.getUtilEseguiRicerca() == null) {
            myForm.setUtilRigaInizio(0);
            myForm.setUtilRigheTabella(righeTabella);
            myForm.setUtilRigheTabellaNew(righeTabellaNew);
            myForm.setUtilImpostaRicerca(Boolean.FALSE);
            myForm.setUtilEseguiRicerca(Boolean.TRUE);
            myForm.setUtilFormModificata(Boolean.FALSE);
        }

        if (myForm.getUtilEseguiRicerca().booleanValue()) {

            lista = loadByWhere(conn, myForm, session);
            myForm.setListaDati(lista);
            myForm.setUtilEseguiRicerca(Boolean.TRUE);
            myForm.setUtilRigaInizio(0);

        } else {
            dao = new CtrkCheckListDAO();
            lista = dao.loadAll(conn);

            myForm.setListaDati(lista);
            myForm.setUtilEseguiRicerca(Boolean.TRUE);
            myForm.setUtilRigaInizio(0);

        }

        myForm.setListaDati(lista);

        //
        // Controllo Rientro da eventuale Elimina
        //
        if (myForm.getUtilRigheTabella() != 0) {
            if (myForm.getUtilRigaInizio() > myForm.getNumRecord() - 1) {
                myForm.setUtilRigaInizio(((myForm.getNumRecord() - righeTabella) > 0) ? myForm
                        .getNumRecord() - righeTabella
                        : 0);
            }
        }

        //
        // Controlli da eseguire se visualizzo un record per pagina
        //
        if (unRecordXPagina) {
            if (myForm.getNumRecord() == 0) {
                myForm.setUtilRigaInizio(0);
                myForm.setUtilRigheTabella(0);
                myForm.setUtilRigheTabellaNew(righeTabellaNew);
            } else {
                myForm.setUtilRigheTabella(righeTabella);
                myForm.setUtilRigheTabellaNew(0);
            }
        }

        myForm.setListaDatiNew(myForm.getUtilRigheTabellaNew());
        myForm.setUtilFormModificata(Boolean.FALSE);

        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }

    private List loadByWhere(Connection conn, TrackingChecklistForm myForm,
            HttpSession session) throws Exception {

        String id_modulo =(String) ((myForm.getN_id_modulo() == null) ? "": myForm.getN_id_modulo());
        String domanda = (myForm.getC_domanda() == null) ? "" : myForm.getC_domanda();
        String flag_attivo = (myForm.getC_flag_attivo() == null) ? "" : myForm.getC_flag_attivo();
        String data_inserimento = (myForm.getD_data_inserimento() == null) ? "": myForm.getD_data_inserimento();
        String data_disattivazione = (myForm.getD_data_disattivazione() == null) ? "": myForm.getD_data_disattivazione();

        String where = "";
        String ctlWhere = "";
        Object[] elementi = new Object[0];

        if (!id_modulo.equals("")) {
            where = where + ctlWhere + "ID_MODULO = '" + id_modulo + "'";
            ctlWhere = " AND ";
        }

        if (!domanda.equals("")) {

            where = where + ctlWhere + "DOMANDA = '" + domanda + "'";
            ctlWhere = " AND ";
        }

        if (!flag_attivo.equals("")) {
            where = where + ctlWhere + "FLAG_ATTIVO = '" + flag_attivo + "'";
            ctlWhere = " AND ";
        }
        if (!data_inserimento.equals("")) {
            where = where + ctlWhere + "DATA_INSERIMENTO = '"
                    + data_inserimento + "'";
            ctlWhere = " AND ";
        }

        if (!data_disattivazione.equals("")) {

            where = where + ctlWhere + "DATA_DISATTIVAZIONE = '"
                    + data_disattivazione + "'";
            ctlWhere = " AND ";
        }

        logger.debug("where : " + where);

        if (!ctlWhere.equals("")) {
            CtrkCheckListDAO dao = new CtrkCheckListDAO();
            String orderBy = "";
            return dao.loadByWhere(conn, where, elementi, orderBy);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private ActionForward gestione(ActionMapping mapping,
            TrackingChecklistForm myForm, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session, Connection conn)
            throws IOException, ServletException, Exception {

        logger.debug("gestione");

        String action = request.getParameter("c_request");
        //
        // Controllo Richiesta Immissione / Aggiungi Righe Immissione
        //
        if (unRecordXPagina) {
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Immissione")) {
                myForm.setUtilEseguiRicerca(Boolean.FALSE);
                return mapping.findForward("success");
            }
        } else {
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Aggiungi Righe Immissione")) {
                myForm.addListaDatiNew(5);
                myForm.setUtilRigheTabellaNew(myForm.getUtilRigheTabellaNew() + 5);
            }
        }

        //
        // Controllo Richiesta Aggiungi Righe Immissione
        //
        if (!unRecordXPagina) {
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Aggiungi Righe Immissione")) {
                return mapping.getInputForward();
            }
        }

        //
        // Controllo Richiesta Uscita
        //
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Uscita")) {
            session.removeAttribute(nomeForm);
            GepoUtente utente = (GepoUtente) session.getAttribute("GepoUtente");
            response.sendRedirect(utente.getReturnURL());
            return null;
        }

        //
        // Controllo Richiesta Esegui Ricerca
        //
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Esegui Ricerca")) {
            try {
                validateRicerca(conn, myForm);
                return mapping.findForward("success");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug(e.getMessage());
                ActionMessages errors = new ActionMessages();
                ActionMessage error = new ActionMessage("errore.generico",
                        e.getMessage(), e);
                errors.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, error);
                saveErrors(request, errors);
                return mapping.getInputForward();
            }
        }

        //
        // Validate Records
        //
        if (!validate(conn, session, myForm)) {
            return mapping.getInputForward();
        }

        //
        // Aggiornamento Tabelle
        //
        if (!aggiorna(conn, myForm)) {
            try {
                conn.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new Exception("Errore ROLLBACK : " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return mapping.getInputForward();

        } else {
            try {
                conn.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new Exception("Errore COMMIT : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        //
        // Aggiornamento Riuscito
        // Imposto default per righe immissione
        //
        if (!unRecordXPagina) {
            myForm.setUtilRigheTabellaNew(righeTabellaNew);
        }

        //
        // Controllo Richiesta Successivo / Precedente
        //
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Successivo")) {
            myForm.setUtilRigaInizio(myForm.getUtilRigaInizio()
                    + myForm.getUtilRigheTabella());
            return mapping.getInputForward();
        }

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Precedente")) {
            myForm.setUtilRigaInizio(((myForm.getUtilRigaInizio() - myForm
                    .getUtilRigheTabella()) > 0) ? myForm.getUtilRigaInizio()
                    - myForm.getUtilRigheTabella() : 0);
            return mapping.getInputForward();
        }

        return mapping.findForward("success");

    }

    private void validateRicerca(Connection conn, TrackingChecklistForm myForm)
            throws Exception {

        String n_id_modulo = (String)  ((myForm.getN_id_modulo() == null) ? ""
                : myForm.getN_id_modulo());
        String c_domanda = (myForm.getC_domanda() == null) ? "" : myForm
                .getC_domanda();
        String c_flag_attivo = (myForm.getC_flag_attivo() == null) ? ""
                : myForm.getC_flag_attivo();
        String d_data_inserimento = (myForm.getD_data_inserimento() == null) ? ""
                : myForm.getD_data_inserimento();
        String d_data_disattivazione = (myForm.getD_data_disattivazione() == null) ? ""
                : myForm.getD_data_disattivazione();

        if (n_id_modulo.equals("") && c_domanda.equals("")
                && c_flag_attivo.equals("") && d_data_inserimento.equals("")
                && d_data_disattivazione.equals("")) {
            myForm.setUtilEseguiRicerca(Boolean.FALSE);
        } else {
            myForm.setUtilEseguiRicerca(Boolean.TRUE);
        }

        myForm.setUtilImpostaRicerca(Boolean.FALSE);
        myForm.setUtilRigaInizio(0);

    }

    private boolean validate(Connection conn, HttpSession session,
            TrackingChecklistForm myForm) throws Exception {

        boolean validato = true;
        TrackingChecklistRecord[] rec = myForm.getListaDati();
        TrackingChecklistRecord[] recNew = myForm.getListaDatiNew();

        for (int x = 0; x < myForm.getUtilRigheTabellaNew(); x++) {

            if (recNew[x].isModificato()) {
                if (!validateRecord(conn, recNew[x])) {
                    validato = false;
                }
                myForm.setDatiNew(recNew[x], x);
                myForm.setUtilFormModificata(Boolean.TRUE);
            }

        }

        int begin = myForm.getUtilRigaInizio();
        int end = (begin + myForm.getUtilRigheTabella()) > rec.length ? rec.length
                : (begin + myForm.getUtilRigheTabella());

        for (int x = begin; x < end; x++) {

            if (rec[x].isModificato()) {
                if (!validateRecord(conn, rec[x])) {
                    validato = false;
                }
                myForm.setDati(rec[x], x);
                myForm.setUtilFormModificata(Boolean.TRUE);
            }

        }
        return validato;
    }

    private boolean validateRecord(Connection conn, TrackingChecklistRecord rec) throws Exception {

        UtilityCtrk rowExist = new UtilityCtrk();
        CtrkCheckListBean vo = new CtrkCheckListBean();
        CtrkCheckListDAO dao = new CtrkCheckListDAO();
        //
        // Control Id modulo
        //
        if (rec.getN_id_modulo().equals("")) {
            rec.setC_errore("Inserire ID MODULO");
            return false;
        }
        //
        // Control Domanda
        //
        if (rec.getC_domanda().equals("")) {
            rec.setC_errore("Inserire DOMANDA");
            return false;
        }
        //
        // Control Flag attivo
        //
        if (rec.getC_flag_attivo().equals("")) {
            rec.setC_errore("Inserire FLAG ATTIVO");
            return false;
        }
        vo.setIdModulo(new BigDecimal(rec.getN_id_modulo()));
        vo.setDomanda(rec.getC_domanda());
        vo.setFlagAttivo(rec.getC_flag_attivo());

        vo.setId(new BigDecimal(GepoUtility.getSequenceNext(conn,
                "SEQ_ID_TRACCIATURA")));

        if (dao.exist(conn, vo)) {
            rec.setC_errore("Record già presente!");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean aggiorna(Connection conn, TrackingChecklistForm myForm)
            throws Exception {

        boolean aggiornato = true;

        TrackingChecklistRecord[] rec = myForm.getListaDati();
        TrackingChecklistRecord[] recNew = myForm.getListaDatiNew();

        int begin = myForm.getUtilRigaInizio();
        int end = (begin + myForm.getUtilRigheTabella()) > rec.length ? rec.length
                : (begin + myForm.getUtilRigheTabella());

        //
        // Loop per DELETE
        //
        for (int x = begin; x < end; x++) {

            try {

                CtrkCheckListBean vo = new CtrkCheckListBean();
                CtrkCheckListDAO dao = new CtrkCheckListDAO();

                if (rec[x].isC_delete()) {
                    vo.setRowid(rec[x].getR_rowid());
                    dao.delete(conn, vo);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                aggiornato = false;
                if (unRecordXPagina) {
                    rec[x].setC_delete(false);
                }
                rec[x].setC_errore(e.getMessage());
                myForm.setDati(rec[x], x);
            }

        }

        //
        // Loop per INSERT
        //
        for (int x = 0; x < myForm.getUtilRigheTabellaNew(); x++) {

            try {

                CtrkCheckListBean vo = new CtrkCheckListBean();
                CtrkCheckListBean voOld = new CtrkCheckListBean();
                CtrkCheckListDAO dao = new CtrkCheckListDAO();

                vo.setIdModulo(string2BigDecimal(recNew[x].getN_id_modulo()));
                voOld.setIdModulo(string2BigDecimal(recNew[x]
                        .getN_id_moduloOld()));
                vo.setDomanda(recNew[x].getC_domanda());
                voOld.setDomanda(recNew[x].getC_domandaOld());
                vo.setFlagAttivo(recNew[x].getC_flag_attivo());
                voOld.setFlagAttivo(recNew[x].getC_flag_attivoOld());
                vo.setDataInserimento(string2Date(recNew[x]
                        .getD_data_inserimento()));
                voOld.setDataInserimento(string2Date(recNew[x]
                        .getD_data_inserimentoOld()));
                vo.setDataDisattivazione(string2Date(recNew[x]
                        .getD_data_disattivazione()));
                voOld.setDataDisattivazione(string2Date(recNew[x]
                        .getD_data_disattivazioneOld()));

                if (!vo.hasEqualMapping(voOld)) {

                    dao.create(conn, vo);
                    logger.debug("Create " + vo);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                aggiornato = false;
                recNew[x].setC_errore(e.getMessage());
                myForm.setDatiNew(rec[x], x);
            }

        }

        //
        // Loop per UPDATE
        //
        for (int x = begin; x < end; x++) {

            try {

                if (!rec[x].isC_delete()) {

                    CtrkCheckListBean vo = new CtrkCheckListBean();
                    CtrkCheckListBean voOld = new CtrkCheckListBean();
                    CtrkCheckListDAO dao = new CtrkCheckListDAO();
                    vo.setRowid(rec[x].getR_rowid());
                    voOld.setRowid(rec[x].getR_rowid());
                    vo.setId(string2BigDecimal(rec[x].getN_id()));
                    voOld.setId(string2BigDecimal(rec[x].getN_idOld()));
                    vo.setIdModulo(string2BigDecimal(rec[x].getN_id_modulo()));
                    voOld.setIdModulo(string2BigDecimal(rec[x]
                            .getN_id_moduloOld()));
                    vo.setDomanda(rec[x].getC_domanda());
                    voOld.setDomanda(rec[x].getC_domandaOld());
                    vo.setFlagAttivo(rec[x].getC_flag_attivo());
                    voOld.setFlagAttivo(rec[x].getC_flag_attivoOld());
                    vo.setDataInserimento(string2Date(rec[x]
                            .getD_data_inserimento()));
                    voOld.setDataInserimento(string2Date(rec[x]
                            .getD_data_inserimentoOld()));
                    vo.setDataDisattivazione(string2Date(rec[x]
                            .getD_data_disattivazione()));
                    voOld.setDataDisattivazione(string2Date(rec[x]
                            .getD_data_disattivazioneOld()));
                    if (!vo.hasEqualMapping(voOld)) {
                        dao.save(conn, vo);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                aggiornato = false;
                rec[x].setC_errore(e.getMessage());
                myForm.setDati(rec[x], x);
            }
        }
        return aggiornato;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant JSP code and display only the related action class method, not the entire action class.

Comment: Post the relevant Java code. The properties of your form couldn't be populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a method that through the exception. Also some other reasons are standing downloads here. I hope this helps

1. The action attribute of a tag must match exactly the path attribute of the action definition in the struts-config.xml file. This is how Struts associates the ActionForm bean with the action.
2. This error usually occurs when you have specified a form name that does not exist in your tag. For example, you specifiec and 'myForm' is not the name of a form associated with myAction in the struts-config file
3. You get this message when Struts is unable to map the data in the HTML form to the properties in your ActionForm bean. Make sure each of the properties on your bean is either a String or a boolean. Do you have any properties of type `java.util.Date` or other objects? That might cause this error. Also check to see that you have public getters and setters for each of your properties.

This sites you could Check:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/53114/Struts/ServletException-BeanUtils-populate

http://javaexceptions1.blogspot.com/2009/08/javaxservletservletexception.html